# How can I find out what os version a blackberyy phone has?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to figure out what phone to use to test my black berry app on where I'm using jde version 6.0

I tried to google emulators, I thought the emulate=or would tell you what jde version its using, but I got the link
https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477
which had a drop down for emulters pertaing to a os version, not a device.

I also googled blackberry phone jde 6.0, this did not work.
Is there a web page that has what os version each phone has?
or I was going to get the storm, does it use 6.0 or higher?
also would any blackberry phone with a camero have 6.0 or higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that unless the model is quite old, the devices within the model can range through multiple OS versions.

For example, the BlackBerry Bold can be found with an OS as old as 4.3 installed on it, but you can also find recent models that come out of the factory with OS 6 installed.

At [Antair](http://www.antair.com), our current device of choice to test on is the BlackBerry Torch. It is one of the more popular models used by consumers these days. It also has a touch-screen and a physical keyboard, and allows the user to flip from portrait to landscape mode. Torch models come out of the factory with RIM OS 6 installed.

So, if you're going to buy a physical device to test on, due to the range of features, the availability of RIM OS 6, and the popularity of the device, I would recommend the BlackBerry Torch.

Comment: Hi,I don't really want tp spend $400 on a torch, looks like bto do it right I'll have to break down and buy the torch, thank you for replying to my quastiopn.

Comment: If you're going to go the less expensive route and decide to purchase an older Bold or Curve model, be careful -- while you can update some recent ones to RIM OS 6 (if you install an OS update manually), if you buy a device that's too old, it won't be able to run RIM OS 6 at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [this page](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) which gives you access to the simulators in a slightly different direction, letting you choose the device model first.